# How to make a prediction from a Multiple Linear Regression

Tags: regression, predictive-models

I am creating a linear regression where:

**Dependent Variable** - Revenue by zipcode

**Independent Variables** - Number of Competitors, Population by zip, and minimum distance from one of our two locations.

What I want to do is see if we added a new location, what would be the revenue of that location? Would it be mathematically correct to go back to each of observations in the regression and put the values and coefficients together assuming the new location existed? If I do this, should I only do it for zip codes where the minimum distance is less to the new location, than to one of our other locations?

Comment: What are the locations? Is that a categorical variable where the levels pick out something special & unique, or is it just a point in space? AFAICT, you could take the distance from a new location & compute it as a function of the distances from your 2 existing locations. If that's true, there isn't really any information in the new location & you could work from what you already have.

Comment: The locations are not a categorical variable. I found an API that calculates the distance between two zip codes. I calculated the distance for every zip  code in my sample, then took the lower number (customers would go closer). So like 47.627 miles or 4.25 miles. One thing I could do is add a dep var for distance to competitor, but the competition has a lot of different sizes.

Comment: You are going to need to add a lot more context to make this interpretable. Please edit your Q to say more about what the study is about, what the data are, what model you're using, what your goals are, etc.

Comment: You may need some kind of population model for your zipcode effect -- a simple random effect is probably not good enough because nearby locations will tend to be be more alike than distant ones. However, as gung says, we could use more information about what you're doing here.